# Random derangement memory leak

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, random

I wrote a Secret Santa program that will read a number of game participants, assign each participant to one of the other participants by random derangement, making sure no participant is assigned to themselves, and send each an email.

It seems to execute properly and give intended output, but returns `free(): invalid pointer` at end of execution before aborting. Am I writing out of bounds somewhere in the `derange()` function that I can't seem to find? Additionally, does my random derangement logic look sound? It seems to test well, but I have a suspicion it does not give a truly random distribution.

Aware there are functions that could make my life easier like `memcpy()`, or even `shuffle()`, but this is mainly a learning exercise for me -- though I do hope to make use of it during the holidays. Be kind, I'm just getting started!

**EDIT :** Cleaned up code for more minimal example.

```
struct person {
    char name[30];
    char emailAddress[30];
    char secretSanta[30];
};

int main(void) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct person * members = (struct person *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct person));
    derange(members, n);
    free(members);
    return 0;
}

void derange(struct person * p, int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int guesses[n];
    int i, j, r;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        r = (rand() % n);
        if(r == i) {
            i = -1;
            // picked its own number, restart loop
        } else {
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(r == guesses[j]) {
                    i = -1;
                    guesses[j] = -1;
                    // number already used, restart main loop
                }
            }
            guesses[i] = r;
            for(j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                p[i].secretSanta[j] = p[r].name[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Additionally, don't cast `malloc()` (i.e. simply write `struct person *members = malloc(sizeof *members * n);`) and don't overrun storage (i.e. `scanf("%29s", p->name);` etc).

Comment: Might be because the second loop of the `else` uses `i` as an index, even after you set it to -1 earlier.

Comment: Phil M has it; but, you also need to initialize the elements of `guesses[]`. Running with `valgrind` as Toby suggested revealed both of these issues.

Comment: You might want to research [**Fisher-Yates shuffle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and consider what you would change to prevent any element ending up in its original position.

Comment: Still very much a beginner, so thanks Toby for the information. I learned in an online course that casting `malloc()` was good housekeeping, so I did it to be safe.

Comment: @TobySpeight Fisher-Yates would have streamlined this a ton, but I'm fairly certain my brute-force method prevents that too. It resets the outer `for()` loop any time it encounters a random number equal to its own index or one that has been used and stored in `guesses[]`.

Comment: @PhilM this is intentional, it resets the outer `for()` loop if the same number is rolled twice.

Comment: Sure - I just meant that unmodified Fisher-Yates wouldn't have the same guarantee, so you couldn't use it without making some change.  I worry that your algorithm might never terminate when the list is large, due to the backtracking.  There's no guarantee of forward progress when you try and try again.

Comment: - `srand(time(NULL));` should be called once per execution (ie., on the main fuction) in order to provide a random distribution, otherwise you're just creating a seed each time you call  `derange()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Good point. I have some print statements in my implementation that show progress during the loop, and for a list of 7 participants it often makes several hundred attempts before finding a valid solution.

Comment: @Miguel thanks for pointing that out. In this case, it only ever gets called once, so I moved it inside the `derange()` function for debugging purposes. But good to know in future.

Comment: @tobiasfried It may be intentional, but it is still screwing things up. You don't actually continue the outer loop after doing that; at least, not before you then use that -1 in `guesses[i] = r;` and the loop immediately following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably end up accessing `guesses[i]` and `p[i]` after you've set `i` to -1:
Add a single line:

```
       } else {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(r == guesses[j]) {
                i = -1;
                guesses[j] = -1;
                // number already used, restart main loop
            }
        }
        if (i == -1) continue; //Prevent accessing guesses[-1]
        guesses[i] = r;
        for(j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            p[i].secretSanta[j] = p[r].name[j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, missed that! Thank you sir.